# kbuildsycoca4 issues after upgrading from Centos 7.3 to 7.4

Tags: centos, corruption, okular

I've taken over supporting a number of users on Centos desktops.

I recently upgraded from Centos 7.3 to 7.4, after the upgrade when the program okular is run from the command line we get the following dumped to the screen periodically.

```
kbuildsycoca4 running...

buildsycoca4(20795) VFolderMenu::loadDoc: Parse error in  "/home/np630/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file" 
kbuildsycoca4(20795) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-visio.template.macroEnabled.main+xml" 
kbuildsycoca4(20795) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" 
kbuildsycoca4(20795) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12"
```

As the users mostly work in terminal windows editing and compiling its causing disruptions in their work flow.

I reinstalled okular and kde-libs, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Where else can I look or what config/setting can i change to fix the issue or at least send the output to a log file and not have it dump to the terminal.

Thanks in advance.